# Why main() is declared public and static in java

Tags: java, static, program-entry-point, public

Why is the main declared as public and static?

```
public static void main(String arg[])
{}
```

acording to ans in java

```
"The method is static because otherwise there would be ambiguity: which constructor should be called?"
```

Comment: What part of the answer did you not understand? We can't help you if we don't know where you're stuck.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

public - The main method is called by the JVM to run the method which is outside the scope of the project therefore the access specifier has to be public to permit a call from anywhere outside the application.

static - When the JVM makes a call to the main method there is no object that exists for the class being called therefore it has to have static method to allow invocation from class.

void - Java is a platform independent language, therefore if it returns some value, then the value may have a different meaning between different platforms so unlike C it can not assume a behavior of returning value to the operating system.